# What should I do when several questions have the same answer but aren't exactly the same question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've been watching C# questions recently and I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411873/ignore-records-that-have-same-value-of-same-property-in-the-ienumerable-c-sharp/59412290#59412290) that could be answered the same way as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551181/remove-duplicate-lists-inside-a-list-of-lists-in-c-sharp) and I'm pretty sure there are many other questions that have the same answer that globaly tells something like

> Use the overload of the `Distinct` method that uses an `IEqualityComparer<T>`

The difference though is that these answers also provide an example for implementing the `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the question's specific case.

To me there are more generic answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property) (and this question's answers can be applied to both previous questions) but what should be done with these questions that look like duplicates?

Comment: You don't have to do anything.  [linq] has the same problem as tags like [regex], [sql].  There are a strictly limited number of lego blocks but an infinite way to snap them together.  There is a learning curve, lots of programmers that ask for help are still climbing it.  And Google never helps them, the fundamental problem that has no easy solution.  Typically you'd get fed up with it after a while, then you add the tag to the "Ignored Tags" section of your profile.

Comment: Indeed ignoring the tag could be a thing even though some questions like the one I mentionned first doesn't even have the [linq] tag. I was more talking about how to deal with the question "for everyone" like marking it as duplicate.

Comment: We like canonical Q+A.  But it just isn't practical for this tag.  There are far, far too many duplicates to choose from, finding the best one is quite hard when Google doesn't help, the OP does not want a tutorial that shows how to snap the pieces together.  So repetitive answers, customized to the OP's specific task, are quite normal.  Some users just don't mind giving such answers over and over again, there is for example a [sql] expert that has posted 55k of them.  That is unusual however, most contributors burn out around 2.5k

Comment: For me the best example is Json. There is a infinite amount of possible json structure. On the  5 time a day question: "How to convert this json to object," / "ReadJson" / "WriteJson" , There will always be someone that will argue that the object have a different name. Meanwhile the question grow 3 to 6 answers that are copy past.  For entertainement purpuse I will recommend following C# + Json / C# + CSV / C# + Regex.

Comment: @xdtTransform and for despair purposes, drop the C# from those pairs...

Comment: @VLAZ, Op is already browsing C# tag. We cannot send him into the zone with Js or Php questions. It's too soon. It's not because you just hit 10k+( Gratz btw, have fun seeing the deleted monsters under the carpet.), that you should traumatize youngsters!

Answer (score 2):

"Duplicate" means "answer to this is already present in the duplicate Q&A". So it is perfectly fine to flag/vote to close as duplciate in this case.

*Should* you flag those as duplicate? Your personal call. Flagging will add "does this answer your question" auto-comment which may expose you to "@#$@ elitists downtroden and duplicize my awesome questions" comments, so try and see how you feel about it. If you particularly like some tag/keyword combination and feel confident to create/maintain a solid canonical Q&A for it may be a route to have a good easy to find duplicate and get at least some reward in reputation by doing so.

Comment: . Yes, flagging as duplicate is the way to go. If you got nasty comments in return, flag them.